How to show a tooltip on a toggleButton that's disabled?
I want to show a tooltip of MUI's ToggleButton when it is disabled
howerver tooltip works fine when ToggleBUtton is not disabled
for disabled it breaks
 <ToggleButton value={item?.key} aria-label="left aligned" key={item?.key} disabled={true} >
             <Tooltip title="Data Not Available" >
                       <span>{item?.value}</span>
             </Tooltip>
  </ToggleButton> 

I am using MUI- both Tooltip and ToggleBUtton are MUI components
and my project is a react project.
I am importing both components as follows-
import ToggleButton from '@mui/material/ToggleButton';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';


There is a ToggleButtonGroup on outer layer and it contains many ToggleButton, some of toggleButton can be disabled and some might now. SO I want to provide tooltip on ToggleBUtton and not ToggleButtonGroup.

This seems to work for me.
<ToggleButtonGroup value={selected} onChange={handleSelection}>
  <ToggleButton value="button1">Button 1</ToggleButton>
  <Tooltip title="Button 2 is disabled" arrow>
    <span>
      <ToggleButton value="button2" disabled>Button 2 (Disabled)</ToggleButton>
    </span>
  </Tooltip>
  <ToggleButton value="button3">Button 3</ToggleButton>
  <Tooltip title="Button 4 is disabled" arrow>
    <span>
      <ToggleButton value="button4" disabled>Button 4 (Disabled)</ToggleButton>
    </span>
  </Tooltip>
</ToggleButtonGroup>



There is a possibility that ToggleButtonGroup can have many ToggleButtons and only few of them are disbaled

Updated the code. Does that help?

@Meg - Did that help?
